# Unable to Update ProgressBar from Firebase Storage UploadTask

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm using Angular2 and Firbase Storage. I'm trying to get the 'uploadProgress' value to update the  (specified in the HTML file) but somehow the 'uploadProgress' variable in the uploadTask.on function just can  be updated. Is it because it is running on another thread? any workaround to this problem? HOpe someone can help me. Thanks

```
=======================================================================
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-folder',
  templateUrl: './create-folder.component.html'
})

 export class CreateFolderComponent { 

 public fItem: FolderItem;
 public f: File;
 public storageRef: Storage;
 public uploadProgress = 0;


constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}
```

onSubmit() {

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('myclient/' +     
this.fItem.file_name);
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(this.f);  


  uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  this.uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *  
  100;


  });

 }


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it because it is running on another thread?

Because it runs in another context.

To solve problem assign **this** to some variable outside 'state_changed' callback function. After that you can use this variable as reference to initial **this** instance.

```
public uploadFile() {
        let self = this;
        ...
        firebaseUploadTask.on('state_changed',
            function progress(snapshot) {
                self.percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            },
            function error(error) {},
            function complete() {}
        );
    }
```